# How can I rearrange the exact sag equation?

Tags: geometric-optics

I apologise if this is a basic question on a site such as this but my maths skills aren't the best.

The exact sag equation is $s = r - \sqrt{(r^2 - y^2)}$. We are required to know in my module that the rearrangement to find $r$ is $r = \frac{(y^2 + s^2)}{2s}$ but I am struggling to rearrange the equation to find this. I asked my professor who told me it was fine to just memorise the equation and not understand how we got there but I would like to understand how we rearranged to find this, both to improve my mathematics and because I can bet I will need to know how we got here for the exam.

I searched online and watched many videos on rearrangements and expanding brackets but struggled to find one similar to this. I found a website where somebody goes through how they rearranged it the link is below. https://www.optiboard.com/forums/showthread.php/15689-Rearranging-the-Sag-formula

They use this as a starting point $r^2 = y^2 + (r - s)^2$ which I understand but then the next step jumps to here $r^2 = y^2 + r^2 - 2rs + s^2$ the step was called after expanding but I am not sure how to expand to get here. I looked at an online calculator which said I should use the perfect square formula and upon researching what this is I became even more confused.

Comment: Ok, learn this identity. $$(a-b)^2=(a-b)(a-b)=a^2-ab-ba+b^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$$

Comment: So I just memorise the equation you put above? Then how do I use it? I am confused

Comment: The key step is this -$$(a-b)(a-b)=a(a-b)-b(a-b)$$

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand. Where does that come from, how do I use it? What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$s=r-\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$$
By transposing the terms,
$$r-s=\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$$
By squaring both the sides of the equation,
$$(r-s)^2=r^2-y^2$$
We know that $(r-s)^2=r^2-2rs+s^2$, so the previous equation becomes
$$r^2-2rs+s^2=r^2-y^2$$
By canceling $r^2$ from both sides,
$$2rs=s^2+y^2$$
or,
$$r=\frac{s^2+y^2}{2s}$$

Comment: Thank you so much I am closer to understanding now. The only thing that is throwing me off is where you have written we know that.... I don't know what that means?

Comment: I have replaced $a$ with $r$ and $b$ with $s$.

Comment: So it should be (r - s)^2 = r^2 - 2rs + s^2? But you haven't written (r - s)^2 in equation. Do we just ignore the first part of the equation? The (a - b)^2 part? Thank you for having patience with me, I'm not the best with numbers. You have got me so close to understanding however so thank you again!

Comment: You got it right.

Comment: I am editing it so maybe it would become more clear.

Comment: You are literally a life saver I understand it all now minus one part. So we divide by 2s to move it across to the right hand side but wouldn't that leave 2r on the left hand side not just r?

Comment: I would like to give you extra points so I will wait until 2 days have past so I can put a bounty on the question and then mark yours as correct as you have helped me out so much! Gone above and beyond, so thank you!

Comment: It would leave only $r$.

Comment: I understand it all! Thank you! As I said I will upvote now but will wait to mark it as an answer once I am able to place a bounty on it. Thank you!